Autogen with LM Studio running llama3
Very new to Autogen. I have a model meta-llama-3.1-8b-instruct running on LMStudio at http://127.0.0.1:1234/v1. I am trying to run the example code provided here at Autogen Getting Started. The difference is , I have changed the config_list to work with LMStudio
import autogen  
import os
import dotenv
from autogen import AssistantAgent, UserProxyAgent

config_list = [{
    "api_type": "open_ai",
    "api_base": "http://127.0.0.1:1234/v1",
    "api_key": "NULL"
}]

llm_config = {
    "request_timeout": 600,
    "seed": 42,
    "config_list": config_list,
    "temperature": 0
}

assistant = AssistantAgent("assistant", llm_config=llm_config)
user_proxy = UserProxyAgent("user_proxy", code_execution_config=False)

# Start the chat
user_proxy.initiate_chat(
    assistant,
    message="Tell me a joke about an egg and chicken.",
)

However, I get the following error. Am I missing something obvious ?

TypeError: Missing required arguments; Expected either ('messages' and
'model') or ('messages', 'model' and 'stream') arguments to be given


I was just working on this also and managed to get it running with llama-3.2-1b running locally on LM Studio.

In your config_list change 'api_base to 'base_url'
In your llm_config add the model name 'model': 'llama-3.2-8b-instruct'

from autogen import AssistantAgent, UserProxyAgent

config_list = [{
    "api_type": "open_ai",
    "base_url": "http://localhost:1234/v1",
    "api_key": "NULL"
}]

llm_config = {
    "seed": 42,
    "config_list": config_list,
    "temperature": 0,
    "model": "llama-3.2-1b-instruct"
}

assistant = AssistantAgent("assistant", llm_config=llm_config)
user_proxy = UserProxyAgent("user_proxy", code_execution_config=False)

# Start the chat
user_proxy.initiate_chat(
    assistant,
    message="Tell me a joke about an egg and chicken.",
)

Example output:
user_proxy (to assistant):

Tell me a joke about an egg and chicken.

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
assistant (to user_proxy):

Here's one:

Why did the egg go to therapy after meeting the chicken?

Because it was cracking under the pressure!

I hope that cracked you up!

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

